# NP Completeness of a Graph Problem, Proof Required

Tags: discrete-mathematics, np-complete, satisfiability

I have a graph problem that I would like to prove NP-completeness. It is outlined below:

> A graph problem compromising of two graphs, say $G_1(V_1,E_1)$ and $G_2(V_2,E_2)$ such that $V_i$ and $E_i$ denote the nodes and edges respectively. An answer to the following question is required:
>
> Does $\exists$ subset $V \subset V_2$ and one-to-one mapping $f:V_1 \to V \ni$ for any $v'\&v'' \in \{V_1\}$, the edge $[v',v'']\in E_1$ iff $[f(v'),f(v'')]\in E_2$?

I think reduction to a 3-sat problem should do the trick, however I have having troubles to actually execute the reduction. I tried out some examples and attempted to convert the graphs into 3-sat, didn't work out as expected. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This is the [subgraph isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgraph_isomorphism_problem) problem.

Comment: @MJD Thanks for letting me know, the first sentence of the article is clear enough, I will give it another go.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use that the CLIQUE problem is NP-Complete, you can use the inclusion map to reduce from CLIQUE to SUBGRAPH-ISOMORPHISM. Here, the subgraph in question is the clique of the specified size.

Comment: I can utilise the fact that the Clique, 3-sat, VCOVER, scheduling, decision, and Hamiltonian Cycle is NP-complete.

Comment: Great! You have your reduction then.